# its or their when talking about body parts

Tags: pronouns

This is a command for a preschool class in which I'm not sure if I need to use *its* or *their*. The command as follows:

"Point to each part of the body and say its name."

The idea is basically that the preschool children point to a part of their body and say the name of that part of the body. Example: Point to head and say "head".

Comment: Use "its" because "part of the body" is singular.

Comment: (1) *Each* → *its*. (2) *All* → *their*. *Each* is singular and *all* is plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each part of the body refers to a part of body, **its** is the correct pronoun

> **Point to each part of the body and say its name**

The command applies to each child though you address the entire class.